# What can I do to take the elements of a stack and add them to a single linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list

I have the following definition for a listNode

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode (int x){
        val = x;
    }
}
```

And I have a stack (variable called valueStack) with a certain number of integers. I want to take the values from the stack, in the first in last out order, and make a single linked list with these values. 
This is what I have right now, but it keeps overwriting over the values and ends up with only a single element in the linked list. This is because I keep reassigning revList to revList.next but I don't know how else to do it:

```
    ListNode revList = new ListNode(valueStack.pop());
    while (!valueStack.isEmpty()){
        ListNode toAdd = new ListNode (valueStack.pop());
        revList.next = toAdd;
        revList = revList.next;
    }
```

Comment: You are using one variable, `revList` to do two jobs, keeping track of the start of the linked list and keeping track of the end, where you need to append the next item. Why not use two variables, one for each job?

Comment: Thank you, I was trying with two variables but I just wasn't getting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (stack.isEmpty())
    return null; // ??? how are you representing an empty list?
ListNode first = new ListNode(stack.pop());
ListNode last = first;
while (!stack.isEmpty())
    last = last.next = new ListNode(stack.pop());
return first;
```

This is what patricia meant by using 2 variables.

The line

```
last = last.next = new ListNode(stack.pop());
```

is just short for these two lines

```
last.next = new ListNode(stack.pop());
last = last.next;
```

Note that if you use these two lines you will need braces for the while loop {}

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. I am still a little unclear as to why it didn't work when I did try using two variables. But I guess I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how the second last line works? 
Why do you do last = last.next = new ListNode (stack.pop())?
And why does that work to change the value of first?

Comment: It was because you overwrote the first node each time you popped an element from the stack (revList = revList.next).  The first node should never change, only the last node.

Comment: I kind of understand what you said, but I am still having a hard time understanding why the variable first also gets updated each time last is changed. Because the value of last is always only one ListNode with next always null. And last keeps getting over written each time. But then how is it that first keeps getting updated with all the correct values?

Comment: The job of `first` is to point to the first element of the list. If you can find that one, all the others can be found by following the `next` pointers.